# Tangent line to an implicitly defined cubic curve

Tags: geometry, tangent-line

> Given the curve defined implicitly below and a point $(1,1)$ on that curve I was asked to find the tangent line at that point. You then have to find all other tangent lines parallel to that one.
>   $$
> x^2 +3x^2y+3xy^2+y^3-7x^2-10xy-7y^2+8x+8y
> =0.
> $$

**My attempt:**
I took the derivative with respect to $x$ of both sides and isolated $dy/dx$.
I found this to be equal to
$$
\frac{10y+14x-3x^2-6xy-8}{3y^2+3x^2-10x-14y+8}.
$$
To find the slope at the given point, I simply substituted in $x = 1$ and $y = 1$ and found $\frac{dy}{dx}$ to be equal to $-0.7$.
To find all other tangent lines I set the second equation equal to $-0.7$.

**But here is my problem**. That equation will give a solution set in the form of a conic, which implies there is an infinite amount of solutions, but a plot of the graph done online shows there cannot be. Many of the points given by the second equation are not on the original curve.

Comment: I'm getting $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{12x-6xy-3y^2+10y-8}{3x^2+6xy+3y^2-10x-14y+8}$.

Comment: But would the solution set still not be infinite(a conic) when it should be finite?

Comment: The solution set of $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\text{whatever}$ will be infinite, but the extra condition that the solutions need to actually be on the given curve will make it finite, I think.